# dplyr: Sum of a constante value in just only one specific level

Tags: r, dplyr

I'll like to apply a sum of a constant value in the variable `x` in the `df` data frame. In my example:

```
df = data.frame(a= sample(1:3,30,replace=TRUE),
                 b= sample(1:100,30,replace=TRUE),
                 x=rnorm(30))
```

Now I like to sum 0.05 to variable `x`, just only in level `3` in the variable `a`, then I try:

```
df2 <- df %>%
     mutate (x2=0.05 + x[a==3])
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `x2`.
x Input `x2` can't be recycled to size 30.
i Input `x2` is `0.05 + x[a == 3]`.
i Input `x2` must be size 30 or 1, not 9.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If there are more than one value having 'a' as 3, it have an issue with the `length`.  In the example showed,

```
nrow(df)
#[1] 30
sum(df$a == 3)
#[1] 13
```

There is a difference in `length`, `mutate` wants the output column (either new or same column) to be of same length as the original.  With `summarise` (from `dplyr` >= 1.0.0), the constraint is relaxed as it can return with number of rows greater than 1 (for each group)

If we need to `sum` only  `first` element of 'x' where 'a' is 3, it can be done

```
df %>%
  mutate(x2 = 0.05 + first(x[a==3]))
```

Another option is to use a logic to fill the rest of the rows with the same value of 'x'

```
df %>%
     mutate(x2 = replace(x, a == 3, 0.05 + x[a==3]))
```

Or a default `NA`

```
df %>%
   mutate(x2 = case_when(a == 3 ~  0.05 + x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here might be some workarounds

```
df %>%
  mutate(x2 = x + ifelse(a == 3, 0.05, 0))
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(x2 = x + 0.05*(a == 3))
```